# Problem with a submit input and jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a form like that:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkpas() 
    {
        var newp = $('#NewPassword').val();
        var newpp = $('#RepeatedNewPassword').val();

        if (newp != newpp) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  </script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
         ...
    <input type="submit" id="sub_btn" value="Edit" onclick="checkpas();" />
<% } %>
```

but that submit input always invokes a form submit, even if I return false in the JS code. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to return the function result:
instead of:

```
<input type="submit" id="sub_btn" value="Edit" onclick="checkpas();" />
```

use:

```
<input type="submit" id="sub_btn" value="Edit" onclick="return checkpas();" />
```

also in your function add an `else return true;`

Answer (score 2):

you need to run onsubmit() not onclick()

Like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#yourformID").submit(function (evt)
    {
        var newp = $('#NewPassword').val();
        var newpp = $('#RepeatedNewPassword').val();

        if (newp != newpp) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  </script>
```

Note assign a form ID by doing this in your ASPX.  here is a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714.aspx

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", Method, new {id="myFormID")})) {%>
```